# How to upload multiple files to Micronaut using Curl?

Tags: curl, micronaut

I need to manage multiple file uploads to my Micronaut controller (multiple parts with the same part name).

I tried the following method:

```
@Post(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
HttpResponse upload(Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> files)
```

and this one:

```
HttpResponse upload(Publisher<Publisher<PartData>> files)
```

I test my API with curl as follows:

```
curl -X POST -F 'data=@/path/to/file1.txt' -F 'data=@/path/to/file2.txt' <SERVER_BASE_URL>/upload
```

or like this:

```
curl -X POST -F 'data=gruik' -F 'data=grok' <SERVER_BASE_URL>/upload
```

Everything I get is the following exception:

```
io.micronaut.web.router.exceptions.UnsatisfiedRouteException: Required argument [Publisher files] not specified
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:279)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:122)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$17(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1360)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate.subscribeActual(FlowableCreate.java:71)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14805)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14752)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14805)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14805)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14752)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14805)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:32)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14805)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14752)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14805)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14755)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.lambda$subscribe$0(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:52)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.subscribe(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14805)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14752)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14805)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14752)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:288)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I know that the error is not related to my code as the upload method is actually empty and just returns `HttpResponse.ok()`.

Is my use of curl incorrect?
Is there a bug in Micronaut?

Many thanks, Folks!

Answer (score 1):

I found my error: the parts' name must match the argument name in the upload method, here `files`.

If I change my curl command to:

```
curl -X POST -F 'files=@/path/to/file1.txt' -F 'files=@/path/to/file2.txt' <SERVER_BASE_URL>/upload
```

It works like a charm.